# Scipys fmin bfgs results in type error and value error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, logistic-regression, valueerror

**Having trouble implementing logistic regression.
This code:**

```
from sigmoid import sigmoid
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from j_cost_reg import j_cost_reg
import csv
from scipy.optimize import fmin_bfgs


data_1415=pd.read_csv(myFile)
y_all=data_1415['R']
X=data_1415.drop(['R'],1)

## MEAN NORMALIZATION
X.insert(0, '0', 1)
mean=X.mean()
std=X.std()
X=(X-mean.transpose())/std.transpose()
#Initialize theta parameters
initial_theta = np.zeros(shape=(X.shape[1], 1))

#regularization term
l = 1

cost, grad = j_cost_reg(initial_theta, X, y_all, l)

def decorated_cost(theta):
    return j_cost_reg(theta, X, y_all, l)

print(fmin_bfgs(decorated_cost, x0=initial_theta))
```

**With this cost function**

```
import numpy as np
##Vectorized implementation with regularization

def j_cost_reg(theta, X, y, l):
        X=np.array(X)
        y=np.array(y)
        theta=np.array(theta)
        theta=np.reshape(theta,(len(theta),1))
        m=len(y)
        y=np.reshape(y,(m,1))
        J=0
        thetareg=theta.copy()
        thetareg[0]=0 #first term shouldn't be regularized
        h=sigmoid(X.dot(theta))
        J=(-1/m)*np.sum((y*np.log(h)+(1-y)*np.log(1-h)))+(l/(2*m))*np.sum(thetareg**2);
        B=h-y
        grad=(X.T).dot(B)+thetareg*(l/m)  
     
        return J, grad.T.flatten()
```

**Result in this error:**

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    J_transposed[i] = df / dx
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**Can anyone figure out the issue?**

I have tried different implementations of the costfunction and how my data is structured but nothing seems to work. I have also tried using cost functions written by others but get the same errors.

Comment: I couldn't find the `J_transposed[i] = df / dx` line in the given code.

Comment: That line is not in my code, but in the code in the scipy package.But that is where the error occurs.